# How to strip all html tags and extract content using java?

Tags: java

I have a requirement to escape all html tags from a string and extract only the content. I will have an HTML content as input. for example

`<html><body><input type=’text’ value=’Hello World’ size=’50’ /> <div> This is a basic example </div><br/><span align=’center’>Hello Sam!!!</span></body><html>`

I need the output as below :

```
Hello World. This is a basic example.
Hello Sam!!!
```

I have tried to use HtmlCleaner and even JSoup. First of all I am not getting any full sample application of them. I was able to extract

```
This is a basic example.
Hello Sam!!!
```

using HTMLCleaner but could not extract the textbox value as it’s an attribute. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html), using JSoup, that shows how to extract attribute values from elements.

Comment: but here my problem is that I don't know exactly what element will come next.

Comment: You can always try to get the value of a non-existing attribute. You get an empty string. So, you could simply loop over all elements, and get data from all the data-holding attributes you care about. http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr(java.lang.String)

Comment: so that means I will need to traverse the nodes recursively and even their attributes even. but how to sense that which kind of element it is means is it div or textbox or something else. if div then i will not traverse it's attributes. but if textbox then i will iterate it's attributes and how will i know that the next attribute is value.

Comment: But it doesn't matter if you try to get the `value` of a `div`, because you will just get back an empty string. You don't need to know what kind of element you are dealing with.

Comment: ok. but it doesn't seem to be an efficient way to do this. Is there no other comparatively easy and efficient way to achieve this? means using some other library like HtmlCleaner, Jericho, HtmlParser, Commons..

Comment: Probably, but it may not be worth the time searching for the _one true way_, depending on your requirements for this project, so I simply offered one solution. And ultimately, that's what any parser has to do anyways (dig through each element) so it's not likely to be much less efficient.

Comment: Yeah you are correct and thanks for your answer. Actually I was looking some less code solution. so that i don't need to iterate through each element. I was searching to do it using some config parameters where I will include attributes list value,href,alt etc ,so that for text field, anchor,image type of elements it can  extract those attributes values automatically.